# Uncaught ReferenceError : require is not defined - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, chart.js

I use Chart.js(new version) as :

```
<script src="~/Plugin/Chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

But when i demo in chrome, i get a error :

```
chart.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCxce.png)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

in your code, pull the bundle instead. E.g ~/Plugin/Chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, I download from chart.js GitHub the library but it havent dist folder.

Comment: its probably easier to use James' answer and pull the bundle from a CDN

Comment: It worked but now I have a new problem GET http://localhost:3000/ng2-charts 404 (Not Found) in zone.js:2019

Answer (score 6):

Use Chart.bundle.min.js bundle found on this page:  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.min.js

Answer (score 4):

For the Angular CLI users -> No need to add this script in angular-cli.json file, because angular-cli should pack ng2-charts lib(and other from node_modules) and add it automatically to your index.html.

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/832

Answer (score 0):

First include the `require.js` file then use *RequireJS*. You can download [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing with Bower.

The solution as proposed in https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/466 was to get specific versions of chart.js and angular-chart.js (tested with angular 1.4.0)

If you use Bower, try this in your bower.json

```
"chart.js": "npm:chart.js#2.1.0",
"angular-chart.js": "1.0.1"
```

and then run: `bower install`

---

If npm:chart.js is not working for you, you need to use a resolver.

1- Add to your .bowerrc:

```
{
  "resolvers": [
    "bower-npm-resolver"
  ]
}
```

2- Install bower-npm-resolver

```
npm install -g bower-npm-resolver
```

3- Now run `bower install` again